# value of selected radio button

Tags: java, swing, radio-button

im new to java swing and im building an application which creates a resume based on user inputs and then displays the resumes created.

i have a label which ask the user whether theyre part of a STEM course or not. so i have two radio buttons which accomplish that task with names :
1.STEM
2.Non STEM

ive added them to a buttongroup so only one is selected.

```
public void groupButton(){
    bg1 = new ButtonGroup();
    bg1.add(stemRadioButton);
    bg1.add(nonStemRadioButton);
}
```

Each time i try to get the value of the radio button selected it keeps returning a null value.

Im new to this and i think it might have been answered and any help would be of great help ! thanks in advance !

EDIT ::
i try retrieving the value by bg1.getSelected().getActionCommand;
ive also tried using the getText method too.

Comment: *"Each time i try to get the value of the radio button selected it keeps returning a null value"*. How are you getting the value? Please post a [mcve] which demonstrates this issue.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach, as @Frakcool suggests.

Answer (score 0):

getText() if you want to get name of radio button